# Report inner loop error

Tags: netlogo

**Code:**

```
to-report check-wall
    hatch 1[
    set color grey
    set size ([size] of one-of walls) / 2
    while [distance myself < (2 * ([size] of myself)) and (pycor + ([size] of one-of walls) / 2)  < max-pycor ]
    [

      fd ([size] of one-of walls) / 2
      if any? walls in-radius size
      [
        report true
        ]
      ]
    die
    ]

  report false
```

**Error:**

> REPORT must be immediately inside a TO-REPORT. error while inboxturtle
>   260 running REPORT   called by procedure CHECK-WALL

Please ignore the functionality of the code. I didn't elaborate it because I don't think it would be required.
*Note:* I wish that when inner if is true it stop the method and return. Thus, creating a variable and setting it true in that if and then returning at the end is not a likely option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an unfortunate limitation of the NetLogo language, that `report` can't be used inside of `ask`, `hatch`, and similar primitives.

But in this case, even if the limitation weren't present, the code still wouldn't be right, because you want to kill the turtle on the way out of the procedure, and just using `report` doesn't accomplish that.

You can fix it as follows:

```
to-report check-wall
  let result false
  hatch 1 [
    ...
    while [not result and ...] [
      ...
      if ... [ set result true ]
    ]
    die
  ]
  report result
end
```